# React does not declare value outside of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a function:

```
let animation = null;
const animationRef = (ref) => {
    console.log(ref);
    animation = ref;
}
```

And at some point later in the code, I need to access animation. But when I print animation at that point, animation is still null. I am certain that animationRef gets called, because the print of ref is shown in the console.
For context, [here](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-fluid-animation/blob/master/example/src/App.js) is an example from the library that calls animationRef. The reason why I am not putting animation into a state is, that it will get accessed using the event handler of [matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Events.html). Animation is both null if I try to access it inside the Event and outside.

When I put an

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(animation);
})
```

After animationRef, it gets printed, but after the next re-render it is null again.

Comment: There are some specifics of React that most of the time cannot be ignored and you have to follow "react" way of doing certain things. Check out [useRef docs](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much :) It worked when I used useRef

Comment: @NoelHug consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) showing the code you used to help future visitors with the same problem as you. As is, the question is missing some key information though and could be improved as well (a [mcve] would be great). Thanks.